# SQL Function for Counting Multiple Variables as "Both"

Tags: sql, function, classification

In this scenario there are two columns.

- Column A = Case ID ( a unique ID for the record)
- Column B = Gender possible values are Male, Female

***Caveat***
If a Case ID is associated with multiple genders it can have multiple records.

Example Data Set:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
Case001  Male        
Case001  Female 
Case002  Male 
Case003  Female 
data set continues...
```

Question: I would like to categorize results as in Case001 where there are two results as "Both". What would be the best way to apporach this solution? Is there a formula or standard way to accomplish this?

Sample Desired Data Set:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
Case001  Both           
Case002  Male 
Case003  Female 
data set continues...
```

Thank you!

I can accomplish with case statement and sub queries. However, I expect there to be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EXISTS in a CASE statement:

```
select distinct
  t.ColumnA,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where ColumnA = t.ColumnA and ColumnB <> t.ColumnB
    ) then 'Both'
    else t.ColumnB
  end
from tablename t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select col1,
       (case when min(gender) = max(gender) then min(gender)
             else 'both'
        end) as gender
from cases c
group by col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`group by` with `having` clauses combined by `union all` as below might be a good alternative :

```
with t( ColumnA, ColumnB ) as
(
 select 'Case001', 'Male'   union all
 select 'Case001', 'Female' union all
 select 'Case002', 'Male'   union all
 select 'Case003', 'Female'    
)    
select ColumnA, 'Both' ColumnB from t group by ColumnA having count(distinct ColumnB) = 2
union all
select ColumnA, max(ColumnB)   from t group by ColumnA having count(distinct ColumnB) = 1;

ColumnA ColumnB
------- -------
Case001 Both
Case002 Male
Case003 Female
```

*Since, there are only two possible cases for genders as having one of them or both of them*

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/JNV19583)</kbd>